# Hamming code in Matlab

Tags: matlab, error-correction, error-detection, hamming-code

I would like to build **Hamming(15, 11)** code with parity bit (SECDED) to correct 1 bit errors and detect 2-bit errors.

Are there any Matlab function that implement encoding and decoding of such code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Communications Systems Toolbox, you can use the [`encode()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/comm/ref/encode.html) and [`decode()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/comm/ref/decode.html) functions.

Comment: I am trying to understand how MATLAB generates Hamming code. I think there is a difference between MATLAB's implementation and this explanation (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hamming-code-for-single-error-correction-double-error-detection)